# Ordinary Differential Equation and linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$-u_{k+1} + 2u_{k} - u_{k-1} = \frac{k}{(n+1)^{3}}$$

With the conditions $u_{0}=0$ and $u_{n+1}=0$, $k=1,...,n$.

The points $P_{k} = \left( \frac{k}{n+1}, u_{k}\right)$, $k= 0,1,...,n+1$ represents $(n+2)$ points on the plane and if you join the points, you have the solution of the problem.

a) Determine the solutions of $Ax=b$ for $n=3$

b) Plot the solutions.

I don't know how to work the ODE with the conditions, if anyone can say me how to start, I would really appreciate it.

PD: I speak spanish, so if I have some mistakes writing, I appreciate it if anyone can fix it.

Comment: Are you sure that this is an ODE  ?

Comment: What is $A$? What is $b$?